# C++: File without BOM in RadStudio

Tags: c++, byte-order-mark

I'm trying to write file without `BOM` in `RadStudio XE3`.

Im using `TStreamWriter` Helper classes for the purpose. The problem is that Everytime `BOM` is writed at the beginnig of the `file`. I want to avoid this. I tried already to change `TEncoding`, i tried almost all options without success. Embarcadero documentation says that if i write file with `UTF7` encoding `BOM` will not be writed to file (again without success).

Am i wrong or is this a compiler issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `TEncoding` used with `TStreamWriter` defines a BOM, `TStreamWriter` will write it.  There is no option to disable that logic.

One way to avoid the BOM would be to derive a new class from `TEncoding` that overrides the virtual `GetPreamble()` method to return an empty byte array, and overrides the other methods to delegate work to another `TEncoding`.